# SUM datetime value by month

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project for an organisation which handles tickets. I am doing this with SQL Management Studio. They want to know how much time they spend for each customer per month. What I have at the moment is individual tickets for each customer. Somehow I need to add these values by month an show in seperate column.

The column EndTime has the total time spend for each ticket, now I want to add these values for each month.

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[Company].Name as CompanyName
    , convert(time(0), CAST(EndTime AS TIME)) AS 'Worked hours'
    ,EndTime
    ,Category.Name as CategoryName

FROM [plugin.tickets].[Ticket]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].Category ON Category.Id = [plugin.tickets].Ticket.CategoryId
    LEFT JOIN [plugin.tickets].TicketActivity  ON TicketActivity.TicketId = [plugin.tickets].Ticket.Id
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].Activity ON Activity.Id = [TicketActivity].ActivityId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].Company ON Company.Id = [plugin.tickets].Ticket.CompanyId
where
           [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].status <= 2
       AND [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].TypeId = 6 or [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].TypeId = 11
       AND [dbo].Category.Name != 'VoIP Telefoni' AND [dbo].Category.Name != 'Beheer'
--      AND [dbo].Activity.EndTime is not null
--      AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME), CAST(EndTime AS TIME)) > 0
GROUP BY 
    [dbo].[Company].Name
    ,EndTime
    ,EndTime
    ,Category.Name

ORDER BY
     'Worked hours' desc
```

[image]

Comment: Aggregating times can be a little tricky. Could the total value be over 24 hours within a given period? SQL Server doesn't support times over 24 Hours (`DATEADD(SECOND,1,CONVERT(time(0),'23:59:59')) = 00:00:00`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have seen the data and we do not exceed 24 hours in total for any ticket :). The main issue here is that I want to add the values for each month keeping in mind that it also just add the month values of the same year only.

Comment: Could you share some sample data, as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements  (**not** as an image), and your expected results please? Provided that you aren't going to go over 24 hours then you can achieve this; the "normal" way would be to aggregate the total time in seconds (or which ever is the smallest time period you want to record), and then add those seconds to the time `'00:00:00'`.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand what u mean by sample data and how can I show expected result.

Comment: Sample Data: *Data that illustrates what your data in your environment looks like in a **consumable** format.* Expected Results: *The results you want to obtain from the sample data you have provided.*